# Extending Core Data generated NSManagedObject classes

Tags: objective-c, core-data, categories, nsmanagedobject, mogenerator

I've been dealing with Core Data for the first time and I wanted to know what the best practices are for extending the classes that Xcode generates for my NSManagedObject entities.

I saw [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator#readme) and I've been also using a similar approach to that as suggested in [SUPER HAPPY EASY FETCHING IN CORE DATA](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/13/super-happy-easy-fetching-in-core-data/).
So I had three kinds of classes:

- The EasyFetching category (only one class);
- A generated NSManagedObject subclass (i.e.: _Entity);
- A custom subclass with some custom methods like finding all the inactive objects, clearing the cache for an object, etc. (i.e.: Entity).

This approach let me do some custom code while I could refactor my Core Data entity and generate it as many times as I needed. But I've also run into some problems like not being able to declare object level methods for my entities (because the NSManagedObjectContext only knew my _Entity classes).

Now I'm using categories to extend my entities functionalities. And this works a lot better because I can have custom object level methods. I now have three kinds of classes:

- The EasyFetching category (as it has a lot of methods that all my custom code uses);
- A generated NSManagedObject subclass (i.e.: Entity);
- A custom category for my NSManagedObject entity (i.e.: Entity+Custom.h).

My question is: what would you recommend?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: That's basically what I've been doing as well: custom categories for my Core Data entities with a few extra methods and such. As for the EasyFetching category, I'm actually using something based on this - https://github.com/halostatue/coredata-easyfetch - which also helps to keep things simple :)

Comment: Seems like it's current state of matters, confirmed here: http://www.sunetos.com/items/2011/07/24/how-to-use-custom-classes-with-core-data-without-fear/

Comment: @piobyz it's great to see all the alternatives explained so people understand the tradeoff. The only thing mission IMO is referring this [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/13/super-happy-easy-fetching-in-core-data/) because it also takes a lot of work when you're doing Core Data related code.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have posted your question as an answer on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577966/should-we-create-model-classes-when-we-use-core-data),
I thought I should answer your question :)

Mogenerator doesn't look bad, give it a try.

Also the way you suggested with categories is also a fine option.

Infact here is a [link](http://www.sunetos.com/items/2011/07/24/how-to-use-custom-classes-with-core-data-without-fear/) that exactly explains How to do so.